# Can an array have more than one array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can I make an array and put another array in it? Like:
`var cars = [[sportCars], [luxuryCars], [automaticCars]]`
Each of the `sportCars` `luxuryCars` `automaticCars` is an unique array and have a unique elemnts.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: why don't you try it and see ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, exactly the way you did in your example.

Note that if `sportCars`, et. al., is an array, the code in your question is adding an extra level by wrapping it in a second array. There's no need to do that, just:

```
var sportCars = ["Ferrari", "Lamborghini"];
var cars = [sportCars];
```

...gives you an array containing an array:

```
console.log(cars[0][0]); // "Ferrari"
```

You don't need (and probably don't want) the extra `[` and `]` around `sportCars` that you have in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var sportCars = ['car1', 'car2'];
var luxuryCars = ['car3'];
var automaticCars = ['car4', 'car5'];
var cars = [sportCars, luxuryCars, automaticCars];
```